# How to get rid of the column sort on a related list

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, salesforce-classic

Is it possible to get rid of this related list column sort? The reason being is that if the related list records are being sorted by a specific column then the sort button in Classic does not work in Lightning since it is overridden by the column sort.

So, after a user clicks on a sort column is there a way for it to be temporary only until the page is refreshed or something of that sort?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but seems like there is no alternative for now..

There is an article with the details:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315141&type=1&mode=1

Hope this helps!!